# Reincarnation into the past

Tags: reincarnation

Does anyone know if according to the system of reincarnation, can a soul reincarnate into the past?
For example, can someone die on 12th Mar 1995 and get reincarnated on 16 June 1856?

Comment: If you're interested in this part of the Torah, you should be aware that Rabbi Pinchas Winston has published a complete translation of the Arizal 's Shar HaGilgulim, which is generally considered the most authoritative Jewish work on reincarnation. The printed version is a bit expensive (though well worth the price) but the e-book will not break anyone's bank: https://thirtysix.org/shop/rabbi-pinchas-winston/shaar-hagilgulim-1/

Comment: Or the whole thing is on chabad.org for free, with excellent translation, diagrams and commentary

Comment: @RabbiKaii Can u please send me the chabad link?

Comment: @RabbiKaii I was unaware of the Chabad.org translation. At a quick glance it looks very well done!

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380302/jewish/Gate-of-Reincarnations-Introduction.htm

Comment: The system of reincarnation is about fixing past mistakes. It only goes forward, according to everything I've seen. In addition, according to many opinions, nothing can go backward in time in Judaism at all.

Comment: @N.T. That's still compatible, since when it comes to fixing mistakes, 'past' and 'future' might be relative to the soul, and not an external clock. For example perhaps someone can make a mistake in their 20th century life and then reincarnate in the 15th century and correct it in that life.

Comment: @user9806 In no discussion of gilgul that I have ever seen does it work that way.

Comment: @N.T. https://www.sefaria.org.il/Vayikra_Rabbah.26.7?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he אָמַר לְפָנָיו מֶלֶךְ רִאשׁוֹן שֶׁיַּעֲמֹד עַל בָּנֶיךָ יִדָּקֵר בְּחֶרֶב, אָמַר לוֹ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא וְלִי אַתָּה אוֹמֵר אֱמֹר אֶל הַכֹּהֲנִים שֶׁהָרַג שֶׁהֵם מְקַטְרְגִים אוֹתוֹ, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: וַיֹּאמֶר ה' אֶל משֶׁה אֱמֹר אֶל הַכֹּהֲנִים בְּנֵי אַהֲרֹן

Comment: @TheGRAPKE What does that have to do with gilgul or this discussion? That is ruach hakodesh.

Comment: @N.T. The *kohanim* hadn't been killed yet.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE So? Shaul hadn't died yet.

Comment: @N.T. Exactly, so time is happening in the wrong order?

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Hashem is giving someone a prophecy of the future. Nothing is happening yet.

Comment: @N.T. That's simply not what the medrash says.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE That's exactly what it says. It is a medrash about Hashem showing Moshe all the future generations.

Comment: @N.T. The medrash says that Hashem said to Moshe that I am telling you *emor el ha'kohanim* in response to the *kohanim* who are currently complaining, but who would only be killed hundreds of years later. Which does not seem to respect the sequential passage of time. (The Divrei Yoel makes this *diyuk*.)

Comment: @TheGRAPKE The Midrash is not saying that. The Meforshim to the Midrash say that the Kohanim were killed after the Kohanim were killed. Hashem is giving Moshe the justification for the future events when they would happen.

Comment: @N.T. That's not how the Satmar Rov reads the medrash.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Source?

Comment: @N.T. I stand corrected, that's how I read the Divrei Yoel (Chelek 6, pg. 210) but it's only the question.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE As long as we get there in the end. The question of Judaism's understanding of time is a fascinating one, but nobody believes it works backwards, with the possible exception of teshuvah.